# How can I suppress warnings emitted by Perl's PDF::Reuse?

Tags: perl, pdf

Is there a way to suppress warnings & error messages in [PDF::Reuse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PDF%3a%3aReuse)? 
(I don't need the warnings...if this part of the script fails for any particular pdf then its ok.)
I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
eval {
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {die "alarm\n"};
alarm 10;

    { 
    local $SIG{__WARN__}=sub{}; 
    use PDF::Reuse;                      
    prFile( $copyPdf ); 
    prDoc(  $file ) ; 
    prEnd() or next;
    }

alarm 0;
}; 

if ($@) {
die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";
print "timed out\n";
}
```

Comment: Your `if` clause makes no sense -- `$@` can never be true and false at the same time.

Comment: @Ether: in Perl, one must never say never. ACME type operations aside, I *have* seen some pretty unthinkably nasty things happen with exception handlers rewriting `$@` out from under you. But I also have no doubt that you are perfectly correct about this case.

Comment: @tchrist: yes, normally we use Try::Tiny these days to avoid worrying about the "$@ is defined but not true" and "$@ just changed, oh noes!" issues. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What warnings are you seeing?

I tried the above script with a PDF I had lying around and got no errors or warnings.  perl 5.8.8, PDF::Reuse 0.35.

Is the problem that one of your PDFs is badly formed?